# gcc giving error on printf while compiling lex output

Tags: lex, flex-lexer

For the example.l lex file I get the error below.  If I comment out the `printf` it goes away.  I though that the top section of the lex specification could contain any arbitrary C code between the `%{` and `%}`.  I need to be able to print some output before lex matches anything.  What is wrong with what I have done and how do I fix it?

```
$ cat example.l 

%{
#include <stdio.h>
printf("foobar\n");
%}

%%

.       ECHO;

$ lex example.l 
$ gcc -g -L/usr/lib/flex-2.5.4a -lfl -o example lex.yy.c
example.l:3: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
example.l:3: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
example.l:3: error: conflicting types for 'printf'
example.l:3: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can't match an empty parameter name list declaration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code here, you can see that one of two things is happening here ... either you are doing a `#include` inside a function body which doesn't make sense, or you are calling `printf()` outside any function, which is equally wrong.

Now, when you take into account this is `flex`, it's the latter. You were probably shooting for something a little more like this:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%

.       ECHO;

%%

int main() {
    printf("foobar\n");
    while (yylex() != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, this seems completely obvious now that you've said it.  Thank you!