# How to fix error in flex/gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, lex

I'm getting an error:

```
 expected declaration of specifiers or '...' before string constant %}
```

when I try to run gcc on a created file from flex. The command I'm using is

```
gcc lex.yy.c test.bc -o output
```

`lex.yy.c` is the flex file I've created using flex in Windows 7.

```
%option 
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
%}
num 0|[1-9][0-9]* {
    printf( "num: %s\n", yytext );}
variable [a-zA-Z]*([0-9]*|[a-zA-Z]*)* {
    printf( "ident: %s\n", yytext );}
symbol ";"|"'"|"("|")"|"{"|"}" {
    printf("Symbol: %s\n", yytext );}
int|if|else|while|for|main {
    printf( "A keyword: %s\n", yytext );}
operator "="|"+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"&&"|"||"|"=="|"!="|">"|">="|"<"|"<=" {
    printf("Operator: %s\n", yytext );}
%%

%%
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
++argv, --argc; /* skip over program name */
if ( argc > 0 )
    yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
else
    yyin = stdin;
yylex();
}
%%
```

Here is what test.bc consists of:

```
main( )
{
int x1;
int x2;
int abc;
if(x1 > 978)
     x2 = abc;
}
```

Comment: Please post the full text of the error messages, especially if there is more than one. Perhaps [this question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166488/gcc-giving-error-on-printf-while-compiling-lex-output), as your `lex` file syntax doesn't seem quite right - your rules should be in between the `%%` lines, I think.

Comment: Did you create `lex.yy.c` from a `.l` source file with `flex`?  What you show is Flex source (though why you have `%option` at the top with no option specified is unclear.  That must be processed by `flex` or a similar program to create a `.c` file that the compiler can understand.  The compiler is clearly unhappy with what you are providing it with.  The role of `test.bc` is mysterious too.  It is appalling C code (antique notation; uninitialized variables; nothing useful done).  You need to clarify what you're doing by editing the question, please.

Comment: Looks like you're combining definitions and rules into a single section. Also you have an extra %% at the end.